# Where do the "fn" and "col" arguments to the Glue column specifications to name columns in dplyr (using `across` and `where` come from?

Tags: r, dplyr, names

I was going through the vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/colwise.html) for column-wise options in `dplyr` and I came across this: (copied verbatim from the vignette)

---

Control how the names are created with the .names argument which takes a glue spec:

```
starwars %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), min_max, .names = "{fn}.{col}"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>   min.height max.height min.mass max.mass min.birth_year max.birth_year
#>        <int>      <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1         66        264       15     1358              8            896
```

---

My question is: where did the variables `fn` and `col` come from? I don't see anything about that on the main `Glue` vignette.  The corresponding arguments to `across` are `.fns` and `.cols` so I don't see the exact correspondence. This seems like too obscure an issue for me to be going on a wild goose chase through the documentation so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: there are often in-function parameters or even subroutines, that cannot be directly called. For example, you note that `n()` is a function. But you can only use it within the context of the verbs given. ie filter,summarise,mutate etc. It can never be used on its own. Itn the same way, dplyr provides the parameters `fn` and `col` for refering to the `.fns` and the `.col` passed to it. WIthout reading the vignettes, one can never know of their existance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the online help for `across`:

.names
A glue specification that describes how to name the output columns. This can use `{col}` to stand for the selected column name, and `{fn}` to stand for the name of the function being applied. The default (`NULL`) is equivalent to `{col}` for the single function case and `{col}_{fn}` for the case where a list is used for `.fns`.